# Shortcode for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am trying to make a shortcode for Wordpress which will display specific posts based on the "id" of the post.

I have found a shortcode example below which displays the most recent posts of "category1".

Any thoughts on what should i do in order to make this work.

```
function pp_recent_work($atts, $content ) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'limit'=>'4',
    'title' => 'Recent Work',
    'orderby'=> 'date',
    'order'=> 'DESC',
    'filters' => '',
    'carousel' => 'yes'
    ), $atts));
    $output = '';
    if($filters){
        $filterstemparray = explode(',', $filters);
        if (count($filterstemparray)>1) {
            $filtersarray = $filterstemparray;

        } else {
            $filtersarray = $filterstemparray[0];
        }
    };
    if($filters=="all" || empty($filters)) {
         $wp_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => array('portfolio'),
                'showposts' => $limit,
                'orderby' => $orderby,
                'order' => $order
                ));
    } else {
       $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('portfolio'),
            'showposts' => $limit,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'filters',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $filtersarray
                    )
                ),
            )
            );
    }

    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

        $id = $wp_query->post->ID;
        $type = get_post_meta($id, 'pp_pf_type', true);
        if($carousel == 'yes') { $output .= '<li class="four columns">'; } else { $output .= '<div class="four columns">';}
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="portfolio-item"><figure>';

        $videothumbtype = ot_get_option('portfolio_videothumb');
            if($type == 'video' && $videothumbtype == 'video') {
            global $wp_embed;
            $videolink = get_post_meta($id, 'incr_pfvideo_link', true);
            $post_embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode('[embed  width="220" height="147"]'.$videolink.'[/embed]') ;
            $output .= '<div class="picture recent_video">'.$post_embed.'</div>';
        } else {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($wp_query->post->ID,'portfolio-thumb');
            }
        }
        $output .= '<figcaption class="item-description"><h5>'.get_the_title().'</h5>';
            $terms = get_the_terms( $wp_query->post->ID, 'filters' );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : $output .= '<span>';
                $filters = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $filters[] = $term->name;
                    if ($i++ > 0) break;
                }
                $outputfilters = join( ", ", $filters ); $output .= $outputfilters;
            $output .= '</span>';
            endif;
}
add_shortcode('recent_work', 'pp_recent_work');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this shortcode

```
function pp_recent_work($atts, $content ) {

    $post_IDS = explode(',', $atts['post_ids']);

    if($filters=="all" || empty($filters)) {
         $wp_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => array('portfolio'),
                'showposts' => $limit,
                'orderby' => $orderby,
                'order' => $order
                ));
    } else {
       $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('portfolio'),
            'showposts' => $limit,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order,
            'post__in'=> array($post_IDS),
            )
        );
    }

    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

        $id = $wp_query->post->ID;

        //do the stuff here

    endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_shortcode('recent_work', 'pp_recent_work');
```

And use the shortcode in pages as `[recent_work post_ids="21,22,23"]` for multiple posts pass IDs as comma separated string

For single Post pass ID as `[recent_work post_ids="21"]`

Answer (score 0):

In your example after the //do the stuff here, I added the following and then added the shortcode you mentioned in a post.

It returns posts from a specific category but not posts with the ids that I specified in the shortcode.

Probably the problem is within the code below?

```
{ $output .= '<div class="four columns">';}
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="portfolio-item"><figure>';

            if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($wp_query->post->ID,'post_ids');
            }

        $output .= '<figcaption class="item-description"><h5>'.get_the_title().'</h5>';
```

Comment: No, this code is just how the post will be displayed. It shouldn't be any problem in which posts are being displayed.